# A question about M.L inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

My attempt:

$|\int_{|z|=R}\frac{Log z}{z^2}|\leq \int_{|z|=R} \frac{log R+\pi}{R^2}\leq \frac{2log R}{R^2}\times2\pi R$.

In the given answer, I need $\sqrt{2}$ in the bound. Can anyone suggest me the mistake in my solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply that $|\log z| = \sqrt{(\log |z|)^2 + ({\rm arg}(z))^2}$.

If $|z| = R > e^\pi$, then $|{\rm arg}(z)| \leq \pi <\log R$, and hence, $|\log z| \leq \sqrt{(\log R)^2 + (\log R)^2} =\sqrt 2 \log R$